# Why is output.eps 0kb?

Tags: gnuplot

I have code:

```
set term eps size 1200,150
set output "output.eps"
set tics out
set xlabel "{/:Italic A} (B)" 
set ylabel " " 
set ytics nomirror 
set xtics nomirror 
unset ytics
unset key 
#set key tc variable
set label "{/:Bold=12 S}" tc rgb "black" at 54250,5.05 
set label "{/:Bold=12 F}" tc rgb "black" at 56170,5.05
set label "{/:Bold=12 R}" tc rgb "black" at 56730,5.05
set arrow from 56000,graph(0,0) to 56000,graph(1,1) nohead dt "-" lw 1 lc rgb "grey30"
set arrow from 56500,graph(0,0) to 56500,graph(1,1) nohead dt "-" lw 1 lc rgb "grey30"
plot 'data.txt' title "{/:Bold T data}" with points pt 7 ps 1 linecolor rgb "black",
```

and the output.eps has 0kb. What is wrong please? output.png is ok with this code.

**Edit**
.png - desired

[image]

.eps

[image]

Comment: How do you call the script? If you call it from inside gnuplot with `load script.plt`or if you type each single command inside gnuplot, then you have to type another `set output` to write the output to disk (or you can quit gnuplot). This behaviour differs from terminal to terminal. If you are on the shell commandline and call your script with `gnuplot script.plt`, then the output should be written immediately for both terminals.

Comment: However .eps image differ from .png. Why? And .eps picture is loading all the time

Comment: What do you mean with "*.eps image differ from .png*"? Different terminals produce different images. And what do you mean with "*.eps picture is loading all the time*"?

Comment: I mean that .eps file is created, it has non-zero size, but when I want to open it, it is loading and nothing displays.

Comment: The .eps file must be closed by gnuplot. How do you call your script? Do you close gnuplot afterwards? Do you call another `set output` command?

Comment: I follow you advise and call `gnuplot script.plt`. I close gnuplot then manually. What you mean with another `set output` commmand?

Answer (score 0):

For some terminals the output file is written when the output is "closed". This can be done by:

- calling the command `set output` after the `plot` command, you have to call another `set output <filename>` when you want another plot
- closing gnuplot, this works automatically if you write your commands into a scriptfile (for example script.plt) and load your gnuplot script from the shell commandline with `gnuplot script.plt`

Comment: Thank you, I used  `term epscairo` and it works, however, the results .png and .eps are different. I added it to my question